# JSON do not work in mockjax

Tags: javascript, jquery

JSON do not work in mockjax? the response return null always.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
I have googleing it, but no result.Can any one help me ?

```
$(function () {
  var isAjaxMocked = true;
  if (isAjaxMocked) {
    $.mockjax({
      url: '/Index.aspx',
      status: 200,
      responseTime: 750,
      responseText: {
        "user": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "david",
            "birthday": "2001/01/26"
          }
        ]
      }
    });
    $.ajax(
      {
        url: '/Index.aspx',
        type: 'GET',
        error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error!');
      },
      success: function (response) {
      var data = response.user;
      alert(response);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $("#msg").append(
          "<ul>" +
          "<li>ID: " + data[i].id + "</li>" +
          "<li>Name: " + data[i].name + "</li>" +
          "<li>Birthday: " + data[i].birthday + "</li>" +
          "</ul>" +
          "<hr />"
        );
      }
    }
  });
}

             });
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(response)` in the `success` handler?

Comment: The `responseText` property is supposed to be a **string**, not an object.

Comment: just add  `dataType: 'json'` solve it

Answer (score 1):

Set contenttype to JSON, like in this sample:

```
$.mockjax({
    url: '/get/stock',
    contentType: 'text/json',
    responseText: {
        items: blabla
    }
});
```

Do this in $.ajax aswell.

Answer (score -1):

just add  `dataType: 'json'` solve it

Comment: Where should it be added to? What does it change?